# Complete validation of text using xpath when it appears multiple times

Tags: css, xpath

I am currently attempting to find a suitable xpath that will help me validate text within a table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1INGX.png

As you can see there are multiple 6's. I want to be able to validate the 6 that is in the same row as 16 (which is under the # of genes column). I have been trying multiple xpaths to click the correct 6, but have been unsuccessful so far.

```
<td id="x-auto-514"
    class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-numGenes "
    style="width: 78px; text-align: center;"
    role="gridcell">
    <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-numGenes"
         unselectable="on"
        >16</div>
</td>
<td id="x-auto-515"
    class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-numSpecies x-grid3-cell-last "
    style="width: 78px; text-align: center;"
    role="gridcell">
    <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-numSpecies"
         unselectable="on"
        >6</div>
</td>
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and simple -- one-liner XPath solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//td[div = '16']/following-sibling::td[1]/div[. = '6']
```

This selects every `div` with string value `'6'` that is the immediate following sibling of a `div` with string value `'16'`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
/html/body/table/tr[
   td/div[
      contains(
         concat(' ',@class,' '),
         ' x-grid3-col-numGenes '
      ) and
      . = 16
   ]
]/td/div[
   contains(
      concat(' ',@class,' '),
      ' x-grid3-col-numSpecies '
   )
]
```

Comment: Sorry it is not.
Maybe I should of been far more specific
So far I have this xpath, //div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-numSpecies')][contains(text(),"6")], which gives the 6, but I was wondering if there is something I can add that there is a 16 next to it.

Comment: Also I use RIDE for my automated testing

Comment: @BoJangles - It seems to work.  I plugged your xml and Alejandro's xpath into the xpath tool at http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx and it evaluated as you indicated it should.  When I changed the '16' in your xml to a '15', it failed.  Isn't that right?

Comment: @gilly3 - That is correct but there there is more code then this. I just used a tiny snippet to show the order of which it is in. If this was all the code then yes it would work. I use firepath along with firebug to check how many potential things can be clicked with the xpath and every 6 was clicked within the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//tr[
    //div[
        contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' x-grid3-col-numGenes ') and
        . = 16
    ]
]//div[
    contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' x-grid3-col-numSpecies ') and
    . = 6
]
```

Comment: This only returned the 6's within the table, but thank you for trying.